# Apache ProxyPass dosen't work with io.socket. GET wss:// url error 400

Tags: apache, websocket, socket.io, proxypass

my domain site use ssl: https://www.irantk.ir

in my firewall only allow http , https protocol and 80,443 port

I decided use ProxyPass, but dosen't work and websocket error 400.
end of my httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
    <Proxy *>
   Require all granted
</Proxy>

Header        set        Connection "Upgrade"
RequestHeader setifempty Connection "Upgrade"
Header        set        Upgrade "websocket"
RequestHeader setifempty Upgrade "websocket"

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

# -----------------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket           [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket                     [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade                    [NC]
RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*)         ws://localhost:10000/socket.io/$1     [P]
ProxyPassReverse /                  ws://localhost:10000/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling           [NC]
RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*)         http://localhost:10000/socket.io/$1   [P]
ProxyPassReverse /                  http://localhost:10000/

RewriteRule ^/socket.io/(.*)        http://localhost:10000/socket.io/$1   [P]
ProxyPassReverse /                  http://localhost:10000/

# -----------------------------------------------------
```